# Confusion on linear transformation theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, independence

Suppose that $T$ is a one-to-one transformation. Show that if the set of images
${T(v_1), ..., T(v_p)}$ is linearly dependent, then ${v_1, ..., v_p}$ is linearly dependent. Why would this imply $T$ maps a linearly independent set onto a linearly independent set.

---

Since ${T(v_1), ..., T(v_p)}$ is linearly dependent then

$0 = c_1T(v_1)+...+c_pT(v_p)$

$0 = T[c_1(v_1)+...+c_p(v_p)]$

> Theorem 11: Let $T:\mathbb{R^n}->\mathbb{R^m}$ be a linear
>   transformation. Then $T$ is one-to-one iff the equation $T(x)=0$ has
>   only the trivial solution.

I'm confused on how Theorem 11 doesn't conflict with the problem. Since the problem said that T is a one-to-one transformation then wouldn't that mean that $\{c_1v_1,...,c_pv_p\}$ has only the trivial solution for when $0 = T[c_1(v_1)+...+c_p(v_p)]$ and is therefore linearly independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem. Since $\left\{T(v_1), ..., T(v_p)\right\}$ is linearly independent there exists a non-trivial combination $$c_1T(v_1)+...+c_pT(v_p)=0.$$
From this you indeed conclude that $T(c_1v_1+...+c_pv_p)=T(0)=0$. By the theorem $c_1v_1+...+c_pv_p=0$, thus they are linearly dependent since there is a non-trivial linear combination that gives $0$. Which you needed to show. This is correct.

Taking the contrapositive of the first statement you see that linearly independent sets get mapped to linearly independent sets if $T$ is injective.